# Cruzar duas tabelas e vincular a linha de uma com a de outra, formando uma terceira

Tags: mysql, sql

Boa tarde, amigos programadores.

Me deparei com o seguinte problema: Tenho duas tabelas, uma com solicitantes, e outra com vagas. Preciso de uma query que cruze as duas tabelas, e pegue a primeira vaga disponível e dê para o primeiro solicitante, fazendo assim uma terceira tabela. Tentei fazer de várias formas, mas sempre que tento, o resultado acaba me dando uma terceira tabela com cada solicitante pegando todas as vagas da tabela. (solicitante 1 pega todas as vagas, então o solicitante 2 pega todas as vagas de novo, e assim por diante)

As tabelas são um pouco extensas, então vou dar apenas as informações principais para melhor entendimento:

Solicitantes:

```
+----+-------------+----------+
| id | Solicitante | id vaga  |
+----+-------------+----------+
| 01 | Joãozinho   |   12345  |
| 02 | Mariazinha  |   12345  |
| 03 | Bruno       |   54321  |
| 04 | Celia       |   54321  |
| 05 | André       |   99999  |
+----+-------------+----------+
```

Vagas:

```
+-----+---------+
| id  | id vaga |
+-----+---------+
| 01  |   12345 |
| 02  |   54321 |
| 03  |   99999 |
| 04  |   99999 |
+-----+---------+
```

A resposta que eu preciso é que ele retorne algo como

```
+-------------+----------+
| Joãozinho   |    12345 |
| Bruno       |    54321 |
| André       |    99999 |
+-------------+----------+
```

ou seja, atribuir a as vagas disponíveis aos primeiros solicitantes a estas vagas.

No momento minha query está deste jeito:

```
SELECT C.Nome_Solic, C.Especialidade,P.Nome_Med,P.Data_Consul,P.Hora_Consul
  FROM [DB_PMSP_CONSULTA].[dbo].[Tabela_Solicitante_HSPM] AS C 
 INNER JOIN [DB_PMSP_CONSULTA].[dbo].[Vagas_Disponiveis_HSPM] AS P ON 
C.Especialidade = P.Espec
```

Alguém teria alguma noção de como posso fazer o que preciso?

Comment: Qual o critério de atribuição de vaga a um solicitante (os menores id primeiro, ordem alfabética, outro critério de seleção...)? E se não houverem vagas suficientes para todos os candidatos ou se não houverem candidatos suficientes para todas as vagas, o que você espera do resultado?

Comment: O critério de distribuição das vagas é, os primeiros a solicitar ficam com as vagas disponíveis. Se não houverem vagas suficientes, os solicitantes que não receberam vagas simplesmente continuam na tabela esperando novas entradas de vagas. Se não houverem candidatos para as vagas, igualmente, a vaga fica na tabela de vagas esperando nova query com dados novos. Esse sistema vai constantemente receber solicitações de vagas e vagas novas diáriamente.

Comment: Pela sua tabela inicial joao e maria estão dispotando a vaga 12345, mas no seu resultado. A maria pegou outra vaga(54321), isso está correto?

Comment: Acho que foi um erro no exemplo somente. Ok, mas e cada registro em `Vagas` corresponde a disponibilidade de uma vaga somente ou pode haver um registro aí que poderia alocar 5 solicitantes, por exemplo?

Comment: Caique, foi erro no exemplo, desculpe.
Diego, vão haver várias vagas pra cada tipo, e muito mais solicitantes por vaga. (em torno de 2 mil solicitantes pra 500 vagas aproximadamente)

Comment: Esse tipo de regra de negócio geralmente fica melhor implementada numa camada de regra de negócio ao invés do BD. Obs: se vc usar um exemplo errado vc vai acabar com uma resposta errada, edite seu exemplo

Comment: Já editei o exemplo.

sim, o ID vagas vai se repetir. As tabelas de vagas geralmente vão vir com vários id vaga repetidos 200~500 vezes, em sequencia. A key fica na primeira coluna em ambos os casos

Comment: Para o resultado que você espera não precisa nem relacionar tabela os dados estão todos na primeira. Acho que tem algo errado no conceito.

Comment: Como eu deveria fazer então? Se importa em me ajudar com isso?

Comment: Veja se a resposta de ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para o que você precisa, primeiro é necessário eliminar a duplicidade de vagas da primeira tabela (Solicitantes) e da segunda tabela (Vagas) e depois relacioná-las pelo id_vaga.

Para obter as demais colunas da tabela, inclua novamente as tabelas (sem o GROUP BY) e relacione pelo ID gerado.

Ficaria desta forma:

```
SELECT C.Solicitante, D.ID_Vaga FROM 
  (SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID, ID_Vaga FROM Solicitantes GROUP BY ID_Vaga) AS A
INNER JOIN 
  (SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID, ID_Vaga FROM Vagas_Disponiveis GROUP BY ID_Vaga) AS B
  ON A.ID_Vaga = B.ID_Vaga
INNER JOIN Solicitantes C ON A.ID = C.ID
INNER JOIN Vagas_Disponiveis D ON B.ID = D.ID;
```

Veja em [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea29ba/1).

Answer (score 1):

Segundo o resultado que você espera não é necessário envolver uma segunda tabela diferente, pois todos os dados estão contidos na primeira.

O que fiz abaixo foi buscar o menor id de solicitante por vaga:

[SQLFiddle - Exemplo online:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/348e95/5)

```
SELECT 
   MIN(ID) AS IDPrimeiroSolicitante
   , IDVAGA AS VagaPrimeiroSolicitante
   , Solicitante
FROM Solicitantes
GROUP BY IDVAGA
```

Comment: Fizemos o que você sugeriu, não está funcionando como deveria.
Você disse que todas as informações estão na primeira tabela, mas não estão, na verdade.
Precisamos saber quantas vagas disponíveis tem para cada ''id vaga'' diferente, e atribuir aquela linha p/ aquele solicitante, até que as linhas de vagas acabem.